# Points in a map with qmplot

Tags: r, google-maps, plot, point

I have to plot some points in a map. I want to use `qmplot`, because it seems simple and effective.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://rpubs.com/jiayiliu/ggmap_examples), but I cannot get it to work:

```
# Libraries
install.packages("maps")
install.packages("ggmap")
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

# Loading European map:     
map <- get_map(location = 'Europe', zoom = 4)
ggmap(map)

# Madrid coordinates
df <- data.frame(lon=c(-3.757324), lat=c(40.441721))

# Plotting the point
qmplot(df$lon, df$lat)
qmplot(df$lon, df$lat, data = df)
```

I get this error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , deparse(substitute(x))) :
>     undefined columns selected

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw your points over the map of Europe you get in the first step, this is what you can do instead:

```
# Libraries
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

# Loading European map:     
map <- get_map(location = 'Europe', zoom = 4)

# Madrid coordinates
df <- data.frame(lon=c(-3.757324), lat=c(40.441721))

ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat))
```

Comment: Thank you, choff.

I have one more doubt. If I have more than 1 point, how can I do for plotting all the points?

This are the points (img): [geom data set][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ7Xv.png

    df <- data.frame(vLon, vLat)
    ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = df$vLon, y = df$vLat), colour = "red", size = 3)

But it doesn't work :-(

Would you be so kind to help me? (or anyone)

Thanks!
Luis

Comment: You can just point the points in your dataframe like before: `df <- data.frame(lon=c(-4,-3,-2), lat=c(39,40,41))`

Comment: Also you do not need to include the `df$` part in your `aes()` because you specified the data already with `data = df`

Comment: Thanks again, Choff. The main problem is that the points will be get from CartoDB (with cartoDB library), so they wouldn't be write in the code. You can see the code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmvwr30c39e1bqd/CartoDB2.R?dl=0 (I couldn't post everything here :-/ ). Kind regards :-)